# Multiple fancybox dialogs on load of page. Only shows the last fancybox

Tags: javascript, fancybox, onload

I am trying to display multiple fancybox dialogs on the load of the page.  I can get one to work, but how do I have the javascript loop stop and not open the other dialog till the user closes the first fancybox?  Right now, I only see the second dialog box.  I will NOT know how many fancybox messages I may have to load on at the start.
Thanks!

Here is the javascript code. (updated)

```
$(document).ready(
    if("0x000000000112009b"!=""){  
        tbRowId="0x000000000112009b".split(",");  
        width="300".split(",");  
        height="300".split(",");  
        $.fancybox({  
            "autoDimensions":"false",  
            "width":width[0],  
            "height":height[0],  
            "transitionIn":"none",  
            "transitionOut":"none",  
            "modal":false,  
            "hideOnOverlayClick":false,  
            "hideOnContentClick":false,  
            "enableEscapeButton":false,  
            "overlayShow":true,  
            "showCloseButton":true,  
            "href":"announce_popup.html?sid=AppjfrfijfdfHvXC&tbRowId="+tbRowId[0],  
            "onClosed":function(){  
                alert("start");  
                $.fancybox({  
                    "autoDimensions":"false",  
                    "width":width[1],  
                    "height":height[1],  
                    "transitionIn":"none",  
                    "transitionOut":"none",  
                    "modal":false,  
                    "hideOnOverlayClick":false,  
                    "hideOnContentClick":false,  
                    "enableEscapeButton":false,  
                    "overlayShow":true,  
                    "showCloseButton":true,  
                    "href":"announce_popup.html?sid=AppjfrfijfdfHvXC&tbRowId="+tbRowId[1]  
                });  
                alert("end.");  
            }  
        });  
    }  
});
```

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one instance of fancyBox can be opened at the time. If you call `$.fancybox({..});` multiple times, then only the last one will be opened. You can use "afterClose" callback to open the next one. Example:

```
$.fancybox.open([{
    href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg',
    title : '1st title'
}
], {
    afterClose : function() {
        //There you can decide if you need to open next one
        $.fancybox.open(
        {
            href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg',
            title : '2nd title'
        });
    }
});​
```

See in action - http://jsfiddle.net/GE7hn/

Comment: We are using version 1.3.4.  I have tried something similar using onClosed instead of afterClose.  It will show the first dialog, but when I close it, I do not get the next one.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I can get my alerts to show, but the second fancy box is not showing.

Comment: So, do I have to get the newer version?  Of course, we have to pay for it

Comment: If you need this functionality, you have to either upgrade or look for alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what you are trying to do, but if you want the user to cycle through each of the messages, you can provide a rel tag like shown here to create groups:

```
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="image_big_1.jpg">
<img src="image_small_1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="image_big_2.jpg"><src="image_small_2.jpg" alt=""/></a>   
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group2" href="image_big_3.jpg"><img src="image_small_3.jpg" alt=""/></a> 
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group2" href="image_big_4.jpg"><img src="image_small_4.jpg" alt=""/></a> 

/* This will create two galleries */

$("a.grouped_elements").fancybox();
```

The code I provided is directly from the fancybox documentation, and I recommend checking it out. If You have javascript creating the messages and links, it will be easy to create groups.

If you need to show the dialog on page load, it is easily accomplished by the following

```
$('.your_group_class').fancybox().trigger('click');
```

Hope I have helped.

Comment: I am not putting the <a> tags on the page.  I am using href to call a program and the content is based on the rowid value that is passed.

Comment: Ok. What you are trying to do looks like it wont work. It looks like you are overriding the initial dialog with the second second dialog. If I am correct, fancybox can't load multiple dialogs at once. You will need to cycle through them some how. Basically what you are doing is forcing fancybox to always show what ever is in announce_popup.html?sid=bdJmcbfaaldxUOWf&tbRowId="+tbRowId[1]. I recommend taking a similar approach to what I showed before. Take the hrefs you are generating on the fly, and insert them as hrefs of an anchor tag.